# A-Frame attach and detach child from parent

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, virtual-reality

I am building an app similar to google street view which can capture images and display them in 360 Equirectangular Image using Aframe.

[image]

One way I thought of doing it is by making an image primitive `<a-image/>` be a child of camera just like the cursor then detach the image at the exact place the camera is looking at.

Please I am looking if there is a way to do such (attaching and detaching) or a better way. I hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with another approach instead of reparenting.

- the outlined rectangle is attached to the camera
- on click (or whatever) - a new plane is created but attached to the scene. It's transfrom is copied from the outlined world transform;

Like this:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("plane-creator", {
    init: function() {
      const tmpV = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0); // helper to store the position vector
      const tmpQ = new THREE.Quaternion(); // helper to store the quaterion

      document.body.addEventListener("click", evt => {
        const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh"); // grab the wireframed plane
        mesh.getWorldPosition(tmpV); // grab the world position
        mesh.getWorldQuaternion(tmpQ); // grab the world rotation (but as a quaternion)

        // create a new plane
        const newPlane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial);
        newPlane.position.copy(tmpV); // apply the position
        newPlane.quaternion.copy(tmpQ); //apply the quaternion
        this.el.sceneEl.object3D.add(newPlane); // attach the new plane to the scene
      })
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
  <a-camera>
    <a-plane position="0 0 -1.5" material="wireframe: true" plane-creator></a-plane>
  </a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Probably best to copy the entire matrix, but i thought a straightforward approach would be more clear.